# Git Flow - Weird behavior merging hotfix to develop

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow, hotfix

I'm getting a strange behavior when merging a **hotfix** into the **develop** branch. It rearranges all the **release** branches into the **develop** branch.

Is it right?

Here is a example

**Before merging the hotfix**

[image]

**After merging the hotfix**

[image]

Comment: This is what `git merge` does. If you only need to merge some commits, use `git cherry-pick` instead.

Comment: You have lots of release branches merged to your hotfix branch, so what exactly do you expect that should happen when you merge hotfix to develop? Also, please define `re-apply`

Comment: @CptBartender It's a default git flow process, all those release branches are already merged into develop

Comment: I think that it's not a technical problem, but the graphic looks very weird... It could be just a optimization from git

Comment: I still don't see where the actual problem is, and I still don't get what you mean by `re-apply`

Comment: Even if your `release/*` branches were merged properly into the `develop` branch (possibly hidden from the diagram), your `develop` branch is definitely missing the merge commits generated from merging the `release/*` branches into `master`. This is why I prefer to merge `master` to `develop` after a release, instead of merging `release/x` to `develop` and `master` separately.

Comment: @CptBartender You're right, re-apply is not the right word, maybe re-arrange

Comment: I added a larger picture and the state before merging as well

Comment: @CodyStott Hmm, I think that I get it... Before merging the hotfix, the develop branch doesn't know anything about master... So, because the hotfix start at the master branch, it needs to add the commit "merge release into master", even if it didn't change any file

Comment: @JonasSchumacher that's pretty much correct, but remember that merging never _creates_ (non-merge) commits, it just joins 2 branches of commits together. Git history is not linear by any means.

Comment: @CptBartender Now I see, it's not reapply neither rearrange, the commit "merge release into master" never was into develop